# Repeat second background image under first image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to use 2 instances of  `background-image` in one `<div>` layer. 
The first `background-image` (which is partly transparent) should be displayed at `top` of the `<div>`, the second should be displayed directly under the the first `background-image` (this works).

Due dynamic content the second image with a height of `1px` should be repeated vertically (`repeat-y`) and start repeating under the first `background-image`. My Problem is when I try to repeat the second `background-image` it is repeated over the whole `<div>` layer.

```
.mainFrameRoundBorder {
    border: none; 
    background: url(../images/theme_box_main_l.png), url(../images/theme_box_main_2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 0;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center top, 0px 364px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: please post a fiddle...  Your description is not very clear.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net    Use this service to make a small example of your code.  I started one for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/E9Xbu/

Comment: i made the example fiddle. the top-image (first background image in the div) has on the top a transparent part the second background image is has the 'repeat-y' value, the second image is repeated over the complete div, also in the transparent part

Comment: sorry forgot the link: http://jsfiddle.net/E9Xbu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the :before or :after pseudo-selectors. You could place your repeating background on the div as you normally do, and then put the non-repeating background in a pseudo-selector element.

This tutorial should be able to give you some good pointers on this method:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Comment: this would normally work, my problem is that the picture on the top is partly transparent and so the repeated image behind would gleam.

Comment: So are you saying that you want the second image to repeat, but only begin repeating after the first has began?

Comment: nearly, i want the second image to begin repeating, when the first image has ended. eg first image has a height of 300px, second image has a height of 50 px. The Div has a height of 500px the second image should start repeating after 300 px(under the first image), in this calculation it should repeat 4 times. What i have now is that it repeats 10 times(also repeats behind the first image).

Comment: Gotcha. You'll need to either not use transparent PNGS (and just repeat the 2nd background underneath the first) or you'll need to use pseudo-selectors. I've made a jsfiddle that shows how you can accomplish this. http://jsfiddle.net/mbxtr/ZRcZw/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `z-index`